# 4 byte unicode character in Java

Tags: java, unicode

I am writing unit tests for my custom StringDatatype, and I need to write down 4 byte unicode character.
"\U" - not working (illegal escape character error)
for example: U+1F701 (0xf0 0x9f 0x9c 0x81). How it can be written in a string?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A Unicode code point is not 4 bytes; it is an integer (ranging, at the moment, from U+0000 to U+10FFFF).

Your 4 bytes are (wild guess) its UTF-8 encoding version (edit: [I was right](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f701/index.htm)).

You need to do this:

```
final char[] chars = Character.toChars(0x1F701);
final String s = new String(chars);
final byte[] asBytes = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

When Java was created, Unicode did not define code points outside the BMP (ie, U+0000 to U+FFFF), which is the reason why a `char` is only 16 bits long (well, OK, this is only a guess, but I think I'm not far off the mark here); since then, well, it had to adapt... And code points outside the BMP need two chars (a leading surrogate and a trailing surrogate -- Java calls these a high and low surrogate respectively). There is no character literal in Java allowing to enter code points outside the BMP directly.

Given that a `char` is, in fact, a UTF-16 code unit and that there *are* string literals for these, you can input this "character" in a String as `"\uD83D\uDF01"` -- or directly as the symbol if your computing environment has support for it.

See also the `CharsetDecoder` and `CharsetEncoder` classes.

See also `String.codePointCount()`, and, since Java 8, `String.codePoints()` (inherited from `CharSequence`).

Comment: Ya. That's one of the few points where C is smarter. `sizeof(wchar_t) == 4` here on my machine.

Comment: Thanks fge. Your solution suits me perfectly.

Comment: @ChristianHujer: Bear in mind that not all C compilers have `sizeof(wchar_t) == 4`, some have `sizeof(wchar_t) == 2`.

Answer (score 12):

`String s = "";`

Technically this is one character. But be careful `s.length()` will returns 2. Also java won't compile `String s = ''`. Java don't promise you that `String.length()` shall returns exact number of characters, it returns just number of java-chars required for store this string.

Real number of characters can be obtained from `s.codePointCount(0, s.length())`.

Answer (score 0):

jshell> String s = "";
s ==> "️"

jshell> s.codePointCount(0, s.length());
$5 ==> 2

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Thanks for contributing to Stack Overflow but can you also add an explanation on how your code solves the problem? Check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for help on code formatting.