# Why does this unicode character end up as 6 bytes with UTF-16 encoding?

Tags: java, unicode

I was playing with a code snippet from the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27287369/4-byte-unicode-character-in-java). I simply added a byte array to use UTF-16 as follows:

```
final char[] chars = Character.toChars(0x1F701);
final String s = new String(chars);
final byte[] asBytes = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
final byte[] asBytes16 = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16);
```

`chars` has 2 elements, which means two 16-bit integers in Java (since the code point is outside of the BMP).

`asBytes` has 4 elements, which corresponds to 32 bits, which is what we'd need to represent two 16-bit integers from chars, so it makes sense.

`asBytes16` has 6 elements, which is what confuses me. Why do we end up with 2 extra bytes when 32 bits is sufficient to represent this unicode character?

Comment: What are the actual bytes? I bet there's a byte order mark (BOM) in the UTF-16 one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UTF-16 bytes start with [Byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-16) `FEFF` to indicate that value is encoded in big-endian. As per wiki BOM is also used to distinguish UTF-16 from UTF-8:

> Neither of these sequences is valid UTF-8, so their presence indicates that the file is not encoded in UTF-8.

You can convert `byte[]` to hex-encoded `String` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9855338/1602555):

```
asBytes   = F09F9C81
asBytes16 = FEFFD83DDF01
```

Comment: Thanks, it is the BOM indeed

Answer (score 3):

> `asBytes` has 4 elements, which corresponds to 32 bits, which is what we'd need to represent two 16-bit integers from chars, so it makes sense.

Actually no, the number of `char`s needed to represent a [codepoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) in Java has nothing to do with it. The number of bytes is directly related to the numeric value of the codepoint itself.

Codepoint U+1F701 (`0x1F701`) uses 17 bits (`11111011100000001`)

`0x1F701` requires 4 bytes in UTF-8 (`F0 9F 9C 81`) to encode its 17 bits.  See the bit distribution chart on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). The algorithm is defined in [RFC 3629](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629).

> `asBytes16` has 6 elements, which is what confuses me. Why do we end up with 2 extra bytes when 32 bits is sufficient to represent this unicode character?

Per the Java documentation for [`StandardCharsets`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html)

> UTF_16
>
> ```
> public static final Charset UTF_16
> ```
>
> Sixteen-bit UCS Transformation Format, **byte order identified by an optional byte-order mark**

`0x1F701` requires 4 bytes in UTF-16 (`D8 3D DF 01`) to encode its 17 bits.  See the bit distribution chart on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16). The algorithm is defined in [RFC 2781](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2781).

UTF-16 is subject to [endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), unlike UTF-8, so `StandardCharsets.UTF_16` includes a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) to specify the actual endian used in the byte array.

To avoid the BOM, use `StandardCharsets.UTF_16BE` or `StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE` as needed:

> UTF_16BE
>
> ```
> public static final Charset UTF_16BE
> ```
>
> Sixteen-bit UCS Transformation Format, **big-endian byte order**
>
> UTF_16LE
>
> ```
> public static final Charset UTF_16LE
> ```
>
> Sixteen-bit UCS Transformation Format, **little-endian byte order**

Since their endian is implied in their names, they don't need to include a BOM in the byte array.